# Ajustar scraping en node (Axios y Cheerio)

Tags: nodejs, axios

buenas a todos. Estoy haciendo una mini app movil, la idea es que tome los datos de una web y los guarde. Todo funciona, pero el problema es que al imprimir los resultados, los guarda a cada uno en una posicion, ahora cuando muestre van a entender.
Mi codigo de scraping es el siguiente:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const SCRAPING_URL = 'https://m.livesoccertv.com/es/competitions/spain/primera-division/';

(async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(SCRAPING_URL)
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  const results = [];

  if (response) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response);

    $('span').each(function() {
      results.push($(this).text());
    });
  }

  console.log(results);
})();
```

Esto imprime:

```
[
  '',                ' Máximos goleadores', 'Clasificación',
  'Granada',         'Athletic Club',       'Eibar',
  'Celta de Vigo',   'Cádiz',               'Osasuna',
  'Barcelona',       'Elche',               'Real Madrid',
  'Getafe',          'Real Valladolid',     'Real Sociedad',
  'Villarreal',      'Huesca',              '',
  'Valencia',        'Levante',             'Deportivo Alavés',
  'Real Betis',      'Getafe',              'Osasuna',
  'Villarreal',      'Eibar',               'Celta de Vigo',
  'Valencia',        'Levante',             'Atlético Madrid',
  'Sevilla',         'Elche',               'Huesca',
  'Cádiz',           'Granada',             'Deportivo Alavés',
  'Real Sociedad',   'Real Madrid',         'Real Betis',
  'Real Valladolid', 'Atlético Madrid',     'Granada',
  'Barcelona',       'Villarreal'
]
```

Y aca mi problema, necesito empezar el scrap a partir de la posición `2` (contando a partir del 0) y luego que junte de a pares, como por ejemplo:

```
[
  { equipo: 'Granada vs Athletic Club' },
  { equipo: 'Eibar vs Celta de Vigo' },
]
```

Así tendría que conseguir que quede, pero no encontré nada por ningun lado.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar un for para iterar tu array y crear un nuevo array de objectos con las strings que necesitas, algo así:

```
const resultsFiltrados = [];

for (i = 0; 4+(i*2) <= results.length; i++) {
  resultsFiltrados.push({equipo:`${results[3+(i*2)]} vs ${results[4+(i*2)]}`})
}

console.log(resultsFiltrados);
```

UPDATE:

Veo que hay unos valores que están vacíos. Puedes filtrar para eliminarlos, así:

```
const preResults = results.filter(data => data!='');

const resultsFiltrados = [];

for (i = 0; 2+(i*2) < preResults.length; i++) {
  resultsFiltrados.push({equipo:`${preResults[2+(i*2)]} vs ${preResults[3+(i*2)]}`})
}

console.log(resultsFiltrados);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto, pero ahora supongamos que quiero agregar otro dato, como por ejemplo `{fecha: 'xx/xx'},` Suponiendo que ya tengo el dato de la fecha, pero no se como implementarlo, para que no de error.

Comment: Aísla el valor de fecha así como hiciste con los equipos de los partidos (supongamos que están en un array que se llama ```fechas```) y cuando utilizas ```push``` en el array final agrega un nuevo elemento al objeto. Así: ```resultsFiltrados.push({equipo:`${results[3+(i*2)]} vs ${results[4+(i*2)]}`, fecha:fechas[i]})```